# About C pointer

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am trying to code something like a stack and develop a function.
It should print out all the elements in the stack in the end.
But all the printed elements are the same, even though the input should be different.
Basically, I used getcwd to store it to a char array.
And then I updated my element by using  element=the char array.

But all the elements are always same as my current path, even if i didn't invoke this function, i just check the s.path using printf.
I also check the address of the elements and found out they always point the same address.

```
int size=0;
char* path[255];

void push(char *input)
{
    char cwd[PATH_MAX];
    getcwd(cwd,PATH_MAX+1);
    path[size]=cwd;
    size++;
    chdir(input);
}
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Without code, we are as clueless as you are. You need to post an MCVE. If you don't know what an MCVE is, go search.

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Show the input, the expected output, and the actual output as text *in the question*.

Comment: Sorry guys i just posted my code

Comment: `path[size]=cwd;`... maybe you mean `strcpy(path, cwd);` ?  But then, after all that, you are simply changing directory to the parameter `input`, without ever having any of your work that occurs previously in the function do anything.

Comment: I can't paste it into a file, compile and run it. That ain't no MCVE!

Comment: i forgot to use strcpy here

Comment: Nevermind guys. Sorry for asking my question in a bad way

Answer (score 0):

A fundamental understanding of how strings are manipulated would be useful to you at this point.  You can find one *[here](http://www.learn-c.org/en/Strings)* or *[here](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-strings)* and many more *[here](https://www.google.com/search?ei=DtONWrn7BsygwASq16yAAw&q=strncpy&oq=strncpy&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i131k1j0i20i263i264k1j0l8.1950.3914.0.4490.7.7.0.0.0.0.330.969.3-3.3.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..4.3.968...0i131i67k1j0i131i20i263i264k1j0i10k1.0.4aj6_XMjPMI)*.

The point being, although it is not clear what you are attempting to do, string functions should be used rather than assignment operators in this section:

```
int size=0;
//char* path[255];// pointer to char array is not needed
char path[PATH_MAX];// char array is sufficient for this purpose.
...
    char cwd[PATH_MAX];
    if(getcwd(cwd,PATH_MAX+1))// use results only if getcwd was successful.
    {
        //path[size]=cwd;// does not work
        strcpy( path, cwd );// this should work
    }
    else
    {
        // handle error
...
```

Also, as noted, you should become familiar with the prototype of the function you are using, and if it does not return `void`, it is usually a good idea to use the value it returns to determine if the results are usable.  If not, handle the error condition, and/or bypass using its results altogether.

Comment: path is an array of pointers to char arrays, but you are suggesting that he strcpy to some point in it...

Comment: @Ben - Nice catch!  I did not see that, and have edited my post.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to save off the string, but it will be lost when you are out of scope.

```
int size=0;
char* path[255];

void push(char *input)
{
    char* cwd = malloc(PATH_MAX * sizeof(char)); // Need a free when popping
    getcwd(cwd,PATH_MAX+1);
    //Save the pointer to the string in an array
    path[size]=cwd; //This doesn't do bounds checking
    size++;
    chdir(input);
}
```